# Dropdown area displays differently in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, css

How do I resize the drop-down area to be consistent with other browsers (Chrome, FF and IE)?

Below is the code:

```
<div id="category-dropdown" style="float:left; display:inline-block; padding:8px 0px 0px 5px; display:none;">
<select name="categories" id="catfield" class="margin-left">
<option value=""> Filter Search...</option>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the drop down arrow to be consistent in all the browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307280/how-to-get-the-drop-down-arrow-to-be-consistent-in-all-the-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Each browser renders the element in its own way !

The Best alternative is to style the element manually and make them appear similar in all browsers..

At the moment, there are no inputs that look the same on all browsers with the **DEFAULT** styles applied.

**ALTERNATIVE 1 :**

> **Note :** "This may or may not work"

Try this -> [Normalize v3.0.0](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

This will make browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.